# How to turn off frozen modules for hydrogen python extension?

Tags: python, debugging, hydrogen

Good day, I installed python 3.11b and when I use hydrogen plugin for Atom it shows me this warning, where and how can I apply these commands below to remove the message?

```
Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
to python to disable frozen modules.
Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would pass `-Xfrozen_modules=off` to `python`. Assuming you are using Python 3, type in your Terminal/PowerShell: `python3 -Xfrozen_modules=off`. Similarly, `python3 PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1`, if you would like to disable the validation process.